# Hibernate LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT propagating on other entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have two entities in my project: `Membership` and `User`. A `Membership` has a `User`. I want an optimistic lock witch increment on read on `Membership` so I added the lockTypeMode when I use find.

```
@Override
public Membership find(Long primaryKey) {
    return em.find(type, primaryKey, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
}
```

I added the @Version annotation.
However, when I tested, I got this error :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: cannot force version increment on non-versioned entity
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.forceVersionIncrement(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1283)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityIncrementVersionProcess.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(EntityIncrementVersionProcess.java:51)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:543)
... 55 more
```

Then I added @Version on `User` and no more error. But the version number is incremented on `User` so I assume I will get `OptimisticLockException` and I don't want this behavior. How can I get rid of the lock on `User` ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to set `@OptimisticLock(excluded=true)` ([Hibernate API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/OptimisticLock.html)) on field User in Membership class:

```
class Membership {   
     ....
     @OptimisticLock(excluded=true)
     User user;       
}
```